# How to path prefix from lazy loaded module components route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a *lazy loading feature module* `calendar.module` loaded in the `app-routing.module` like

```
{
  path: "calendars",
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  loadChildren: () =>
    import("./calendars/calendar.module").then((m) => m.CalendarModule),
}
```

Now, I have a `CraftMapComponent` inside the `calendar.module`

[image]

I would like to access this component without the *calendar* pre-fix like this.

> http://localhost:4200/teacher/craft-map

But all I can do in the `calendar-routing.ts` is to add route like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CalendarComponent, children: [
    { path: 'teacher/craft-map', component: CraftMapComponent }
  ]}
];
```

or

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CalendarComponent },
  { path: 'teacher/craft-map', component: CraftMapComponent }
];
```

But both will resolve to

> http://localhost:4200/calendar/teacher/craft-map

Is there a way by which I **can omit the calendar prefix and still use the lazy load module**?

Comment: in path string You make write what You want

Comment: @TomaszVizaint: Thanks. I was asking whether there is any way to override that 'prefix'

Comment: Yes, is depend how is You routerLink, because if in path You wite {path: 'mylink', ....} in routerLink simple write routerLink="/mylink",

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do that, since the `craftmap`'s route is a child of `calendar` route.

It's like traversing a tree, but you'd want to jump to a descendant directly, without traversing its ancestors first.

Also, note that you might not want to use `CanActivate` with lazy loaded modules, since with `CanActivate`, although it may return `false`, the module would be loaded either way, which might not be the expected behavior. I'd recommend using `CanLoad`, because if it fails(e.g returns `false`), you'll know for sure that the module won't be loaded.

Comment: Thanks. I guess there is no way then.

I am preloading the lazy loaded module.Hence the `canActivate`. It will be loiaded anyway